# How to make y axis lie on x=0?

Tags: plot, octave

I want x=0 to be on the y axis. Right now it doesn't work. I tried to make this command but it is not working

`set(gca, "yaxislocation", "zero")`

My code.

```
labels = [0 128 256 512 1024 2048]; % Provide your labels here
ylabels = [0 1 2 4 8 16 32]; % Provide your labels here

hold on;

% system1 durations in seconds

plot (3, 1 ,'o' ,"markersize", 12);
plot (4, 1, 'o' ,"markersize", 12);
plot (5, 30, 'o' ,"markersize", 12);
plot (6, 150, 'o' ,"markersize", 12);

% system2 durations in seconds

plot (3, 2 ,'x' ,"markersize", 12, "markerfacecolor", "auto");
plot (4, 2, 'x' ,"markersize", 12, "markerfacecolor", "auto");
plot (5, 10, 'x' ,"markersize", 12, "markerfacecolor", "auto");
plot (6, 30, 'x' ,"markersize", 12, "markerfacecolor", "auto");

% system3 durations in seconds

plot (3, 2 ,'d' ,"markersize", 12, "markerfacecolor", "auto");
plot (4, 7, 'd' ,"markersize", 12, "markerfacecolor", "auto");
plot (5, 18, 'd' ,"markersize", 12, "markerfacecolor", "auto");
plot (6, 22, 'd' ,"markersize", 12, "markerfacecolor", "auto");

%set(gca, 'xtick', x); % Change the x-axis so only the right amount of ticks remain
%set(gca, 'xticklabel', labels) % Change the labels to the desired ones
%set(gca, 'yticklabel', ylabels) % Change the labels to the desired ones
%set(gca, "xaxislocation", "zero")
set(gca, "yaxislocation", "zero")
%axis([0,1, miny, maxy]); axis "autox";
```

I'm trying to display exponential scale on both y and x axes but it is impossible.  My conclusion is that octave is useless, gnuplot doesn't work either, and that it is better to draw the graph manually. Neither matlab nor octave can make such a simple thing as exponential scale and they can't even put zero where it belongs.

Comment: According to [this bug report](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?47966): "The 'zero' option is only useful with the gnuplot toolkit. The OpenGL graphics toolkits such as FLTK and Qt do not implement it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been added with changeset http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/rev/1ddb53b6ad30 and is already part of the GNU Octave 4.2.0 release.

Since you aren't mentioning the used version or if you get an warning or error message I can just guess you are using an older version

Edit: I'm not really sure if OpenGL support for (x/y)axislocation was already part of 4.2.0. I can say for sure that it works on current development sources and that it works on 4.2.0 with `graphics_toolkit gnuplot`

Comment: It is version 4.0.0 I use.

Comment: Any reason you are using a version which was released in 2015?

Comment: I can't install any newer. I have to download it manually. I use Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Ubuntu has a PPA for Octave http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Debian_systems#Octave.27s_Personal_Package_Archive_.28PPA.29_for_Ubuntu

Comment: And that repository contains 4.0.2. I'm trying to do something simple and now I must compile C.

Comment: I'm trying to build 4.2.0 from sources now. Maybe it is better if I just write a python or java program for the graph since it also involves a transformation to exponential coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

> I want x=0 to be on the y axis.

To me the sounds like you're trying make the plot start from 0 on the x axis. 
So what you're looking for is for a function to set the x-axis limits.

The [`xlim`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlim.html) function does just that, or you can use [`axis`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html) more generally to set both the x and y axis limits at the same time. See [the octave documentation page on this](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Axis-Configuration.html).

E.g. to make the x-axis start from 0 and go up to 100:

```
xlim([0,100]);
```

Note that the `yaxislocation` does something entirely different.
See https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/examples/controlling-axis-location.html?searchHighlight=yaxislocation&s_tid=doc_srchtitle

**If what you're trying to do instead is make the y-axis and its labels always appear on the x=0 line even if this is in the middle of the graph**, as opposed to, say, fixed at the left-hand side or right-hand side of the figure, then follow the instructions on that link. Essentially:

```
set(gca, 'yaxislocation', 'origin');
```

(Note: the value 'zero' used to be a valid value for this parameter, but this has been deprecated in favour of the value 'origin' which does the same thing).